# Getting Null value from request.getParameter()

Tags: jsp, servlets

In my application,with the help of joining,I am showing the dynamic value in my jsp page like this :

```
<%  while(rs.next()){ %>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onclick="selectall()"></td> 
<td><input type="text"  name="empId" value="<%= rs.getString(1)%> "   disabled="disabled"  maxlength="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="device" value="<%= rs.getString(2)%>"   disabled="disabled" maxlength="10"></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="features" value="<%= rs.getString(3)%>"  disabled="disabled" maxlength="60"></td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" disabled="disabled"></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="policyName" value="<%= rs.getString(4)%>"  disabled="disabled" maxlength="10"></td>
</tr>
<% } 
%>
```

And whenever from another servlet(as I want to show the fetching from this jsp to another jsp ) I am calling `request.getParameter("empId")`,it is fetching the "NULL" value.I think,I have to use set(`session.setAttribute()` or `request.setParameter()`).

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: why there is an i tag here?
name="<i>empId"

Answer (score 2):

Might be because of the disabled attribute .. maybe you can replace it with readonly instead?

Comment: can you show some code? it should look like this: <input type="text"  name="empId" value="<%= rs.getString(1)%>" READONLY maxlength="10">. If you remove the disabled attribute you will not get NULL right?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to say you need to pass values between 2 jsp pages? Then you could use it by setting it in a hidden input field or set it in session...

check if this helps you... [Using request.setAttribute in a JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229937/using-request-setattribute-in-a-jsp-page)

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way.

You can add a hidden type .

```
<td><input type="text" value="<%= rs.getString(1)%> "   disabled="disabled"  maxlength="10"></td>
<td><input type="hidden"  name="empId" value="<%= rs.getString(1)%> "  maxlength="10"></td>
```

Answer (score -2):

try `request.getParameter("empID")` for the field named `empId` not `<i>empId`. Hope that helped , just rename the field in the form